# Removing element from an array using foreach

Tags: php, html, arrays

this is my array output

```
Array ( [0] => Site=[121] [1] => #asasasas [2] => Devices=34343 [3] => DeviceID=[hjhghg])
```

Now I want to remove the value with key if it value contains `#` symbol...
 I have tried this, but does not seem to work....

```
foreach ($myarray as $key=>$value) {
    if (strpos($value,'#') !== false) {
        unset(($myarray[$key]);
    }
}
```

any ways to fix this??

Updated this is my actual array `array_values($lines)` i have already tried this...

```
if(strpos($value,'#') !== false) {
                           unset(array_values($lines)[$key]);
                       }
```

Comment: try removing extra `(` in `unset`

Answer (score 1):

You have one too many opening parentheses after `unset`

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me

```
$arr = array (  0 => 'Site=[121]',
        1 => '#asasasas',
        2 => 'Devices=34343', 
        3 => 'DeviceID=[hjhghg]'
      );
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
  if(strpos($val,'#') !== false) {
       unset($arr[$key]);
   }
}
print_r($arr);
```